# IPSec-tools packages

Tags: packages, ipsec

Are these two packages are different things?  (1 and 2)

1. apt-get install **ipsec-tools**

vs

2. apt-get install **racoon**

I thought racoon is contained inside the ipsec-tools packages.
Why need both of them? I'm not sure whether is ok to install ipsec-tools only?

Thank you all.

Comment: `apt-get` will tell you what it is going to fetch and install when you run that command. Why not try it out and see what package changes will occur? You can always `n` to decline the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ipsec-tools RPM package contains essential libraries, daemons, and configuration files for setting up the IPsec connection.

This includes
`/sbin/racoon`, which is the IKE key management daemon, used to manage and control security associations and key sharing between IPsec-connected systems.

Comment: I'm not a sudo user, I'm wondering whether apt-get install ipsec-tools already include the racoon or not. Or maybe I still need to install racoon. THanks